# When to use $\mathbb{P}$ vs P or $\mathbb{E}$ vs E?

Tags: soft-question, notation

When should I use $\mathbb{E}$ versus $E$ for expectation and $\mathbb{P}$ versus $P$ for probability-of?

Comment: When you have time and when it will help understanding

Comment: They are identical?

Comment: I always use $\mathbb P$ and $\mathbb E$, but it is personal preference.

Comment: I have over dozen books on probability theory and none of them use $\mathbb P$ and $\mathbb E$. I prefer the plain $P$ and $E$.

Comment: It is totally up to your preference. In some paper, even the mixture of $\mathbb{P}$, $P$, and $\mathsf{P}$ is used simultaneously to denote different objects from different probabilistic settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use whatever font you prefer.

The reason for using a distinct font is just to visibly distinguish the operator from variables.